# Error installing Mongify

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, mongodb, mongify

I installed all the utilities required to run **mongify** as mentioned [here](http://linuxpitstop.com/migrate-mysql-to-mongodb-using-mongify-utility-linux/) but I am still getting this error-

```
/home//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem mongify (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /home//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /home//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/mongify:22:in `<main>'
    from /home//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

This is my gem list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activemodel (4.2.7.1)
activerecord (4.2.7.1)
activesupport (4.2.7.1)
arel (6.0.4)
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.8)
bson (1.12.5)
bson_ext (1.12.5)
builder (3.2.3)
bundler (1.14.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
highline (1.7.8)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.5)
json (default: 1.8.3)
json_pure (2.0.3)
minitest (5.8.3)
mongify (1.3.1)
mongo (1.12.5)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (default: 2.0.17)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (5.0.0, default: 4.2.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubygems-update (2.6.10)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (3.1.5)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a gems error.

First you need to locate '**Gemfile**'

Then run - **cd /.gemspecs/did_you_mean-1.0.0**

then run - **bundle install --with production**

then if it is not installed run- **gem install mysql2**

Now all the required gems are installed.

Now run - **mongify**

Now if mongify is working you need to check the connection of SQL and NoSQL

So run - **mongify check database.config**

In database.config file you need this-

```
sql_connection do
adapter   "mysql2"
host      "127.0.0.1"
username  "root"
password  "root"
database  "database_name"
end    

mongodb_connection do
host      "127.0.0.1"
database  "database_name"
end
```

Now you will see -

**SQL connection works**

**NoSQL connection works**

Then run - **mongify translation database.config > translation.rb**

And - **mongify process database.config translation.rb**

Now Data will be migrated from MySQL DB to MongoDB.

To know more details reagarding ***mongify*** read this [link](https://github.com/anlek/mongify)

Comment: So the reason is the installation of gem `mysql` adapter?

Comment: Yeah and also all the required bundles were not installed

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the gem `mongify`? if you used `bundler`, it would help you fix all dependencies, like

`» gem install mongify

Fetching: activemodel-4.2.7.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activemodel-4.2.7.1
Fetching: arel-6.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed arel-6.0.4
Fetching: activerecord-4.2.7.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-4.2.7.1
Fetching: bson-1.12.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bson-1.12.5
Fetching: mongo-1.12.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mongo-1.12.5
Fetching: bson_ext-1.12.5.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed bson_ext-1.12.5
Fetching: highline-1.7.8.gem (100%)
Successfully installed highline-1.7.8
Fetching: mongify-1.3.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mongify-1.3.1
8 gems installed`

or, do you sure you got error while you installing that gem? checked your error message, looks like you executed that gem cli `mongify`? 
Please paste your full error message. I will update my answer.

Comment: When I run **mongify** on my terminal, this is the error I am getting-


**/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem mongify (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
 from /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
 from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/mongify:22:in `<main>'
 from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
 from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'**

Comment: What's your current user? the `root` or your self? the location content you pasted is weird check your current user.

Comment: Could you try to update the `gem` and `bundler`? then `bundle install` again.

Comment: The current user is myself.When I run update_rubygems I am getting this error-
**/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem rubygems-update (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
 from /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
 from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/update_rubygems:22:in `<main>'
 from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
 from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'**

Answer (score 0):

```
For Mac:
 1.  Download and install the mysql installer. (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)
 Open Terminal
 2.  sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```